# Time syncing between two Ubuntu 16.04 desktops havinginternet connection

Tags: ubuntu, synchronization, ubuntu-16.04, ros, unix-timestamp

I have two Ubuntu 16.04 desktops with ROS installed on both of them. I am publishing data on using one of the computers and subscribing to that data on the other computer. I have written a little script that calculates the latency. The script measures the current Unix time with the unix timestamp associated with the data. But, I am getting negative latency (i.e. I receive data before it is published) which doesn't make sense.

There is obviously an issue of time sync between the two machines. My assumption was that the Ubuntu system connected to internet is already in sync. We don't need to perform any other synchronization. Am I wrong in that assumption? Do, I need to perform some kind of synchronization between the two machines?

Thank you!

Comment: You can not get accurate latency of your internal network by syncing your two computer clocks from the internet and using system clock to calculate the difference, not directly at least. The least you would have to do would be to figure out the time difference between the two computers. More reasonable approach would probably be to sync the computers with PTP instead of NTP. Most modern network cards support PTP.

Comment: Also, not sure, why you need to know the latency, if you are doing some very time-critical things (more time critical than the NTP time syncronisation difference between two PCs) then you will need to probably sync your PCs with PTP for better accuracy. If it is not that time-critical then why not just get the latency between the two PCs with standard tools like ping.

I guess what I'm saying is, is that it would be better to add some context to your question as in what is the problem you are trying to solve with the synchronization.

Comment: @MRFalcon thank you for your reply. I want to control a vehicle in real time based on the video feed I receive. As the vehicle is moving, I need to find the time lag I have in receiving images. This will help me with my analysis of maximum speed I can go at without crashing.

Comment: @ doggie_breath's solution is most probably accurate enough for your use-case. As far a I can tell syncinc locally with chrony will get your clocks to be within hundreds of microseconds. Using PTP you could get sub microsecond synchronization. But even a difference of a millisecond would be of very little consequence in a teleop setup *IMO. Anyway, if you would like to try out PTP [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/fedora/rawhide/system-administrators-guide/servers/Configuring_PTP_Using_ptp4l/) is a link to a tutorial, it is fedora based so you might need to adjust it.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, when running ROS across multiple machines you can definitely run into timing issues. How big of a difference are you generally seeing?

The ROS recommended solution is is to use a package called [chrony](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/). You can use it to specifically sync the clocks on your two machines. Over the same LAN, they should be synced down to at least the microsecond. It can just be installed VIA apt,

```
sudo apt install chrony
```

Then you can just set one computer to be the `master` and have it sync with the NTP server, and have the other sync its time with the `master`.